# Cannot create Interface instance in Springboot HttpExchange

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, microservices, webclient

I am trying to access a endpoint from different microservice using HttpExchange once I create a instance from the client interface it's always returns null value

my RegisterServiceClient interface looks like this

```
@HttpExchange   // Declarative client
public interface RegisterServiceClient {

//    @PostExchange("/ecommerce/loginwithusername")
//    public int ValidateUserWithUsername(@RequestBody String username, String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;

    @PostExchange("/ecommerce/loginwithemail")
    public int ValidateUserWithEmail(@RequestBody LoginUser loginUser) throws UnsupportedEncodingException ;


    }
```

and my configuration is like this

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebClientConfig {

        @Autowired
        private LoadBalancedExchangeFilterFunction filterFunction;


        @Bean
        public WebClient registerWebClient() {
            return WebClient.builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://register-service")
                    .filter(filterFunction)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public RegisterServiceClient registerClient() {
            HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory
                    = HttpServiceProxyFactory
                    .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(registerWebClient()))
                    .build();
            return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(RegisterServiceClient.class);
        }
    }
```

```
@Autowired
private RegisterServiceClient registerServiceClient ;
```

registerServiceClient always have null value why ?

Comment: if you also will add `@Componet` is it will work ?

Comment: I have added but not solved the problem

Comment: but the class where are you trying to inject it is annotated as a spring bean, i mean `@Service` or any others spring component annotations ?

Comment: @Service annotaion